# JQuery - Select td in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

Hello I'am learning jquery, and I have a problem with following code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>organisation Name</th>
          <th>User name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Contact No</th>
          <th>IP</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr> <td>3</td>
        <td>Harshit </td>
        <td>AtulSaini</td>
        <td>arpitkumar@gmail.com</td>
        <td>7860458</td>
        <td>::1</td>
        <td>14/03/2015</td><td><button id="status"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></botton></td></tr>

        <tr class="warning"> <td>4</td>
        <td>Meghaa.co.edu</td>
        <td>megha</td>
        <td>meghaa.sing@gmail.com</td>
        <td>7860458</td>
        <td>::1</td>
        <td>14/03/2015</td><td><button id="status"><span class="label label-warning">Deactive</span></botton></td>
        </tr>            

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want jquery solution.
When I click button having `id=status`,
the first td of that perticular `<tr>` gets selected 
and sent using Ajax.
In response, the class of that `<tr>` toggles from warning to success, and `<button>` span class also toggles from `label-warning` to `label-success`.

Here is the code I tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#status").click(function(){
              var id=$(this tr).find('td:first').html();
              var status=$("span").html();
              var xmlhttp;  
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    alert(res);
                    if(res=="n")
                    {
                      $(this tr).removeClass("success");
                      $(this tr).addClass("warning");                      
                    }
                    else{
                     $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("warning");
                      $(this).parents('tr').addClass("success");
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/update.php?id="+id+"&status="+status,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            });
        });
```

Comment: can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition - use class instead

Comment: And, what is 'botton'?

Comment: It's "button", not "botton"... correct that in your code.

Comment: If OP is using a modern enough browser (supports HTML5) you can create your own html elements, also `botton` is allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#status").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).children("tr").find('td:first').html();
        var status = $("span").html();
        $.ajax({
            url : "scripts/update.php",
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                "id" : id,
                "status" : status
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            },
            success : function(entry) {
                var res = entry;
                alert(res);
                if (res == "n") {
                    $(this).children("tr").removeClass("success");
                    $(this).children("tr").addClass("warning");
                } else {
                    $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("warning");
                    $(this).parents('tr').addClass("success");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Try to use JQuery ajax its faster and easyer to use and you have much less code. And of corse you don't have to care about cross browser problems. Hope i can help.

Comment: hello to all 
Thank you for your reply
**Hans** 
brother the problem is still there the code is working on the first tr perfectly but it not working on any other tr
and in addition i dont why this code is sending only one variable "status " in get request and it is no sending id valiable

Comment: Its simple because there are multiple TR in you patent object, for all you need to use .each on the childrens.

Answer (score 0):

Since you comment my solution, i realized what you realy want to do with the code so now here is a modified version wich should work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#status").click(function() {
        var status = $("span").html();
        $(this).children("tr").each(function() {
            var id = $(this).find('td:first').html();
            $.ajax({
                url : "scripts/update.php",
                type : 'GET',
                data : {
                    "id" : id,
                    "status" : status
                },
                error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                },
                success : function(entry) {
                    var res = entry;
                    alert(res);
                    if (res == "n") {
                        $(this).children("tr").removeClass("success");
                        $(this).children("tr").addClass("warning");
                    } else {
                        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("warning");
                        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("success");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. Have a nice day Hans Petersburg

Edit: Maybe you have to ajust the objects for the add or remove function

Comment: Maybe to avoid some errors you should check if the element even contains the class you want to remove.